# Jlabel text multiplying and overlapping when using update(graphic)

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I've written this code to update my progress bar progress message. Basically, when I have length processes that run on for() loops, I throw this in the loop, and have it update with prog = i and max = an array max.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= array.length-1; i++){
//Process
setPrg(this.lbl, ths.prg, i, array.length-1, "Doing so process");
}
```

-

```
public void setPrg(JLabel lbl, JProgressBar prg, int prog, int max, String msg) {
    prg.setMaximum(max);
    if (prog <= max) {
        prg.setValue(prog);
    }
    prg.update(prg.getGraphics());
    if (prog >= max) {
        setMessage(lbl, "");
    } else {
        setMessage(lbl, msg);
    }
}

    public void setMessage(JLabel lbl, String msg) {
        lbl.setText(msg);
        lbl.update(lbl.getGraphics());
    }
```

I do this with multiple consecutive for() loops, which each have unique messages describing the process.

The problem is, for some reason the label text overlaps over itself. For example, if I have one loop that runs this code:

```
setPrg(this.lbl, ths.prg, i, array.length-1, "This is process 1");
```

And one that runs this code:

```
setPrg(this.lbl, ths.prg, i, array.length-1, "The second process this is");
```

Then the text from the two messages will overlap as soon as the second process starts, instead of "This is process 1" disappearing.

On the other hand, if I don't include this line:

```
lbl.update(lbl.getGraphics());
```

No text will show up at all during the loop, and only the last text set for the label will show up after the loop.

Help much appreciated!

Here's the full program:

```
package test;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Main() {
        initComponents();
    }
 public void setPrg(JLabel lbl, JProgressBar prg, int prog, int max, String msg) {
        prg.setMaximum(max);
        if (prog <= max) {
            prg.setValue(prog);
        }
        prg.update(prg.getGraphics());
        if (prog >= max) {
            setMessage(lbl, "");
        } else {
            setMessage(lbl, msg);
        }
    }

    public void setMessage(JLabel lbl, String msg) {
        lbl.setText(msg);
        lbl.update(lbl.getGraphics());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jProgressBar1 = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("Button");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");

        jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(246, 246, 246)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(226, 226, 226)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jButton1)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jProgressBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 540, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(108, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jProgressBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(40, 40, 40))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
            this.setPrg(jLabel1, jProgressBar1, i, 10000, "Message 1");
        }
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
            this.setPrg(jLabel1, jProgressBar1, i, 10000, "Second Message");
        }
    }                                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Main().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    public javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    public javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    public javax.swing.JProgressBar jProgressBar1;
    public javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: `lbl.update(lbl.getGraphics())` is meaningless; you should remove it.  By any chance is your label a subclass with an overridden paint or paintComponent method?

Comment: "unique messages describing the process" Do you run few threads?

Comment: Is your code executed on the EventDispatchThread or is it on a WorkerThread?

Comment: @VGR If I remove it the text won't show up though. The label is just a plain old Jlabel, haven't manually overridden anything

Comment: [mcve] please. Let's avoid needless confusion and guessing.

Comment: @Alexander I haven't done any threading, it's just running in a regular method

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You have 100% of the relevant code, only thing left out is the interface code autogenerated by Netbeans. Just think of it as a button that you press that goes through two for loops and updates a label and progressbar.

Comment: re, `"you have 100% of the relevant code..."` -- You don't appear to fully understand how difficult it is to find bugs in someone else's code. Til you're sitting in our shoes, please avoid making such statements.

Comment: About all I can tell you so far is that this code, `lbl.update(lbl.getGraphics());` is bad and shouldn't be in your program. That and your program is likely not respecting Swing threading rules.

Comment: Also, please do look at the [JProgressBar Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html). It shows you with example code how to use JProgressBars with long-running processes, including use with a SwingWorker, which is what you want to do.

Comment: And in fact, that's likely the correct solution for your overall problem: use a SwingWorker for the long-running task, within it, set its progress property, attach a listener to the worker to be notified of changes to this property, and then update the JLabel and the JProgressBar from this listener, a PropertyChangeListener. The specifics of the solution will all depend on code that you've not shown.

Comment: [Some examples of use of both SwingWorker and JProgressBar](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=user%3a522444%20swingworker%20jprogressbar)

Comment: I will check those all out and post back with what I come up with, thanks

Comment: @Zhiming010: Thank you for the updated code. Yes, your problem is just as I guessed -- your code does not respect Swing threading, and in fact ignores general threading rules, which is why you're program is misbehaving. The solution is as per the tutorial that I linked to, and the code examples of mine that I linked to -- use a SwingWorker for a background thread, and update your Swing components on the Swing event thread. Now do you see why we requested better code be posted? Until you know the source of the problem, how can you tell if your posted code is sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is a classic one of running long-running code on the Swing event thread, as well as making invalid Swing graphics calls. The solution is to do long-running code in a background thread, such as the doInBackground method of a SwingWorker, and to take care to make all Swing calls on the Swing event thread.

All of this is well explained in tutorials that are easy to find, including

- [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/): how to use a SwingWorker
- [JProgressBar Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html)

For example, compile and run this:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Main4b extends JPanel {
    private static final int MAX = 10000;
    private static final int PREF_W = 400;
    private static final int PREF_H = 200;
    private ButtonAction buttonAction = new ButtonAction();
    private JButton button = new JButton(buttonAction);
    private JTextField jTextField1 = new JTextField("jTextField1", 10);
    private JLabel jLabel1 = new JLabel("jLabel1");
    private JProgressBar jProgressBar1 = new JProgressBar(0, MAX);

    public Main4b() {
        jProgressBar1.setStringPainted(true);

        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        add(new JPanel() {{add(button);}});
        add(new JPanel() {{add(jTextField1);}});
        add(new JPanel() {{add(jLabel1);}});
        add(jProgressBar1);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension superSz = super.getPreferredSize();
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return superSz;
        }
        int prefW = Math.max(superSz.width, PREF_W);
        int prefH = Math.max(superSz.height, PREF_H);
        return new Dimension(prefW, prefH);
    }

    private class ButtonAction extends AbstractAction {
        public ButtonAction() {
            super("Button");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setEnabled(false); // make the button non-pressable

            // create background thread worker
            MyWorker myWorker = new MyWorker();

            // add propertychange listener to it
            myWorker.addPropertyChangeListener(new WorkerListener());

            // run the worker thread
            myWorker.execute();
        }
    }

    // background thread
    private static class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer> {
        private static final String MY_PROGRESS = "my progress";
        private int myProgress = 0;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            // all this code is run in a background thread

            // do this twice
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {

                // iterate from 0 to 10,000
                for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
                    Thread.sleep(1); // small delay so we can see what we're doing
                    setMyProgress(i + j * MAX); // send output to listeners
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public int getMyProgress() {
            return myProgress;
        }

        // myProgress is a "bound" field, one that will notify listeners
        // if it is changed
        public void setMyProgress(int myProgress) {
            int oldValue = this.myProgress;
            int newValue = myProgress;
            this.myProgress = myProgress;
            // notify all listeners
            firePropertyChange(MY_PROGRESS, oldValue, newValue);
        }

    }

    private class WorkerListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
        private String message = "Message %d: %05d";

        public WorkerListener() {
            jLabel1.setText(String.format(message, 1, 0));
        }

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            // all this code is run on the Swing event thread

            // listen for changes to my progress bound field
            if (MyWorker.MY_PROGRESS.equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                int value = (int) evt.getNewValue(); // get value
                int newMsgIndex = 1 + value / MAX; // message number 
                jProgressBar1.setValue(value % MAX); // set value on progress bar
                jLabel1.setText(String.format(message, newMsgIndex, value % MAX));
            } else if (evt.getNewValue() == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
                // worker is done
                jLabel1.setText(""); // reset JLabel
                buttonAction.setEnabled(true);  // re-enable JButton's Action
                MyWorker myWorker = (MyWorker) evt.getSource();
                try {
                    // always call this to catch and handle any exceptions that 
                    // may have been thrown from within the worker
                    myWorker.get();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Main4b mainPanel = new Main4b();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you are using Swing you are automatically in a multi threaded environment. One is the main-Thread and Swing uses the EDT for UI repainting.

Use *SwingUtilities.invokeLater()* to execute *JProgressBar.setValue()* and *JLabel.setValue()* on the EventDispatchThread. This ensures they will be updated accordingly.

An example snippet of how to use *SwingUtilities*.

```
    final JProgressBar prg = new JProgressBar();
    final JLabel lbl = new JLabel();

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            prg.setValue(70);
            lbl.setText("Text");
        }
    });
```

And you will see, that your calls to *lbl.update(lbl.getGraphics());* are no longer needed.

Comment: I tried this, but it still doesn't update... so now the progress bar doesn't show  any change

Comment: `public void setPrg(final JLabel lbl, final JProgressBar prg, final int prog, final int max, final String msg) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                prg.setMaximum(max);
                if (prog <= max) {
                    prg.setValue(prog);
                }
                if (prog >= max) {
                    lbl.setText("");
                } else {
                    lbl.setText(msg);
                }
            }
        });
    }`